# <hr> tag in Twitter Bootstrap not functioning correctly?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div>
<h1>Welcome TeamName1</h1>
  asdf
  <hr>
  asdf

</div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

The hr tag does not seem to work as I would expect it. Instead of drawing a line, it creates a gap, like so:

> [image]

Answer (score 144, accepted):

the css property of `<hr>` are :

```
hr {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-image: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  border-color: #EEEEEE -moz-use-text-color #FFFFFF;
  border-style: solid none;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  margin: 18px 0;
}
```

It correspond to a 1px horizontal line with a very light grey and vertical margin of 18px.

and because `<hr>` is inside a `<div>` without class the width depends on the content of the `<div>`

if you would like the `<hr>` to be full width, replace `<div>` with `<div class='row'><div class='span12'>` (with according closing tags).

If you expect something different, describe what you expect by adding a comment.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize you had to include the <hr> inside of a <div>. Odd.

Comment: I'm assuming span12 has been removed from Bootstrap at some point in the past two years because I don't have it, but putting my body content and the horizontal rule both in row classes worked for me.

Comment: fix `border-color: #EEEEEE -moz-use-text-color #FFFFFF;` with only `border-color: #EEEEEE;`

Comment: span12 has been replaced by col-sm-12

Comment: This part of your code (`border-width: 1px 0;`) cause a `2px` horizontal line! You should change it to:  `border-width: 1px 0 0 0;` to make a `1px` horizontal line.

Answer (score 46):

Instead of writing

```
<hr>
```

Write

```
<hr class="col-xs-12">
```

And it will display full width as normal.

Comment: `<div class="w-100"><hr></div>`

Comment: This is the most elegant solution for Bootstrap, thank you!

Comment: `<hr class="w-100">` seems to be a more self-evident method to set the width.

Answer (score 41):

I solved this by setting the HR background-color to black like so:

```
<hr style="width: 100%; color: black; height: 1px; background-color:black;" />
```

Comment: This is not exactly solving the problem, more like a hack... There are many better ways to over-ride the bootstrap styling than with an inline style.

Comment: Please elaborate @DjangoBurger and share your solution.

Comment: I think @DjangoBurger is mostly complaining about inline styles. You could have put this style in a class and assigned the classname here. I modified your solution that way for my own use, so thank you!

Comment: Agreed - that's an elegant remedy :)

Comment: Works perfectly! I am using bootstrap and somehow my <hr> was unusual - it was transparent and not clearly seen.

Answer (score 17):

It is because Bootstrap's **DEFAULT CSS** for `<hr />` is ::

```
hr {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
```

it creates 40px gap between those two lines

so if you want to change any particular `<hr />` margin style in your page you may try something like this ::

```
<hr style="margin-bottom:5px !important; margin-top:5px !important; " />
```

if you want to change appearance/other styles of any particular `<hr />`  in your page like color and border type or thickness the you may try something like :

```
<hr style="border-top: 1px dotted #000000 !important; " />
```

for all `<hr />` in your page

```
<style>
   hr {
       border-top: 1px dotted #000000 !important;
       margin-bottom:5px !important; 
       margin-top:5px !important;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, the `hr` element in Twitter Bootstrap CSS file has a top and bottom margin of `18px`. That's what creates a gap. If you want the gap to be smaller you'll need to adjust margin property of the `hr` element.

In your example, do something like this:

```
.container hr {
margin: 2px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it would look better if we add border-color : transparent as per below:

```
<hr style="width: 100%; background-color: black; height: 1px; border-color : transparent;" />
```

If you don't put the border transparent it will be white and i don't think that is good all time.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to customize the hrTag by editing the inline styling as such:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- You can also position the row if need be. -->
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12"><!-- set width of column I wanted mine to stretch most of the screen-->
<hr style="min-width:85%; background-color:#a1a1a1 !important; height:1px;"/>
</div>
 </div>
```

The hrTag is now thicker and more visible; it's also a darker gray color.
The bootstrap code is actually very flexible. As the snippet demonstrates above, you can use inline styling or your own custom code. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You may want one of these, so to correspond to the Bootstrap layout:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <hr >
</div>

<!-- or -->

<div class="col-xs-12">
    <hr style="border-style: dashed; border-top-width: 2px;">
</div>

<!-- or -->

<div class="col-xs-12">
    <hr class="col-xs-1" style="border-style: dashed; border-top-width: 2px;">
</div>
```

Without a `DIV` grid element included, layout may brake on different devices.