# Bootstrap positions <hr> line in an odd way

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mv5ut6sw/

I have a list of links at the top of my webpage contained in a `<div>`.  I would like a horizontal `<hr>` line above and below this `<div>` to visually separate the links from the rest of the page.  Simplified example:

```
<hr>
<div style="float:left; width:100%">
    <div style="float:left; margin-right:20px">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/link1">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/link2">Link2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; margin-right:20px">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/link3">Link3</a></li>
        <li><a href="/link4">Link4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

I am using bootstrap to pretty the page up.  Without bootstrap, the `<hr>`s behave as expected, appearing above and below the link section.  When I use bootstrap, however, the two horizontal lines both appear above the link section.

I am at a loss.  I don't want to edit bootstrap code.  Is there inline css I can include to fix this weird placement?

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577712/hr-tag-in-twitter-bootstrap-not-functioning-correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because floats take the elements out of the flow...either you can clear the float value `clear:both` or by applying `overflow:hidden` in the parent div...

Well If you are using **bootstrap4** then why use `floats`...just Use `d-flex` class on the parent div

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h3 style="background-color: lightgray; height: 40px; padding: 2px">
    Ye old title
  </h3>
  <hr>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/go/entry">Race Entry</a></li>
      <li><a href="/go">Start</a></li>
      <li><a href="/go/transfer">Position Transfer</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contracts">Contracts</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/statement">Statements</a></li>
      <li><a href="/position">Race Position</a></li>
      <li><a href="/firm">Advertising Firm</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/report1">Report1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/report2">Report2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/settleit">Settle it!</a></li>
      <li><a href="/upload">Upload</a></li>
      <li><a href="/search">Search</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <hr>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

> "Is there inline css I can include to fix this weird placement?"

It's because of the floats. Just clear the last `<hr>`..

```
<hr style="clear:both;">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s9L0Lf9b/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
<h3 style="background-color: lightgray; height: 40px; padding: 2px">
   Ye old title
</h3>
<hr>
  <div style="float:left; width:100%;">
    <div style="float:left; margin-right:20px">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/go/entry">Race Entry</a></li>
        <li><a href="/go">Start</a></li>
        <li><a href="/go/transfer">Position Transfer</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contracts">Contracts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; margin-right:20px">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/statement">Statements</a></li>
        <li><a href="/position">Race Position</a></li>
        <li><a href="/firm">Advertising Firm</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; margin-right:20px">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/report1">Report1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/report2">Report2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; margin-right:20px">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/settleit">Settle it!</a></li>
        <li><a href="/upload">Upload</a></li>
        <li><a href="/search">Search</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<hr style="clear:both;">
  </body>
```

> "The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from
>   the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its
>   container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it." __ [from MDN posted on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188510/why-a-div-with-float-right-does-not-respect-the-margin-of-the-hr-tag-below/20188655)

P.S. - There's no need to use floats with Bootstrap 4.